# Ajax button listener not adding to shopping cart

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, bootstrap-4

I am working on a small shopping cart application where a user can select different cars and rent/buy them. I am using `ajax` to listen to my `button click` event. When the user clicks `Add to Cart` it should add the car to my `shopping cart`. The number of items in the `cart` should change also. Right now when I click `Add to cart` nothing happens. I double checked my `button listener` but I don't see where the error is happening. I checked my `chrome console` but the only error I get is `not being able to load images from database`. Any ideas or help would be appreciated. I will post my code down below.

`jQuery v2.2.0`
`bootstrap v3.3.6`
`php v7.1.19`

`Update`: I think the issue is that since I am not able to retrieve the images from my database, it doesn't know what to add. I am looking into this.

`Update2`: I am now able to retrieve the images from the database and show them on the screen. I tried debuggin my `ajax` by adding `alert(data)` where data is whats passed into the callback if successful. When I click `Add to Cart` it says `undefined`.

`Update3`: After doing some debugging I got the error `product_id is not defined` in my `ajax` request.

`Update4`: After running the `ajax code` into `chrome developer`, I am getting an `OK` for the `statusText` and also `200` for the `status`. I had to comment out the `data` that is sent and it was able to work. But when I click `Add to Cart` the cart is not being updated?

`index.php`

```
<?php

session_start();
// Connect to database
$connect = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root","", "rentalCar");

?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
   <br />
   <!-- Car Inventory will display across the screen -->
   <div class = "container" style="width:1000px;">
     <h2 align="center"> Car Inventory</h2></br>

     <!-- Two tabs for cart. Nav tabs does this for us  -->
     <ul class = "nav nav-tabs">
     <!-- active defines current page in tab and data toggle is the specific tab
        href will show the Inventory and Cart
      -->
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#products">Product</a></li>
     <!-- The condition will check the value of the shopping cart varialbe if its set or not
     It will then display whats in our shopping cart -->
        <li class="active">
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#cart">Cart
                <span class="badge">
            <?php
            if(isset($_SESSION['shopping_cart']))
            {  
            //  This will show how many items in the cart 
              echo count($_SESSION['shopping_cart']);
            }else{
                    // If theres nothing in the cart then print 0
                     echo '0';
                 }
             ?>
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
     <!-- } -->
      <!-- ?></span> </a></li> -->
    </ul>



    <div class="tab-content">
    <!-- Display things to add into cart -->
         <div id="products" class="tab-pane fade in active">
         <?php
         // fetch everything from the cars table and store in result variable
         $query = "select * from cars";
         $result = mysqli_query($connect,$query) or die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
         // We are fetching everything from the cars table
         while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

         ?>
         <div class = "col-md-4" style = "margin-top:12px;">

            <div style = "border:1px solid #333; background-color:#f1f1f1;border-radius:5px;
            padding:16px; height:350px;" align="center">

            <!-- we are printing the images from db to the screen -->
            <img src = "/Users/moe/Desktop/Web-FinalProject2/moe/<?php echo $row['carPic']; ?>" class="img-responsive" />

            <!-- name of the car -->
            <h4 class="text-info"><?php echo $row['manufactor'];?></h4>
            <h4 class="text-info"><?php echo $row['carType'];?></h4>


           <!-- price of the car -->
            <h4 class = "text-danger"><?php echo $row['carPrice'];?></h4>



            <!-- The amount of car you want to rent -->
            <!-- id quantity in jquery below
            Here we get the number of cars we want to rent and store into quantity -->
            <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity"<?php echo $row[''];?>



             <input type = "hiden" name="hidden_name" id="name<?php echo $row["manufactor"];?>" value="<?php echo $row[""]; ?>" /> 
            <!-- the code above shows the type of the car in the box?
            I think i should change the id="name" to the name of the car. The name attribute
            is in the jquery also -->

            <!-- the next line will store the prices -->
            <input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" id="price <?php echo $row['carPrice'];?>" value="<?php echo $row['carPrice'];?>" />

            <!-- This line will be the button you click to add to the cart -->
            <!-- Each car is unique since the id for it is based on the vinNumber -->
            <!-- The Ajax for the add_to_cart is at the bottom -->
            <input type="button" name="add_to_cart" id="<?php echo $row["vinNum"];?>" class="btn btn-warning form-control add_to_cart" style= "margin-top:5px;" value="Add to Cart" /> 
        </div>
    </div>

        <?php

            }
        ?>

    </div>

    <!-- We wanna display the shopping cart details here -->
     <div id = "cart" class="tab-pane fade">
     <!-- displays order details -->
        <div class="table-responsive" id="order_table">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    <th width = "40%"> Car Name</th>
                    <th width = "10%"> Quantity</th>
                    <th width = "20%"> Price</th>
                    <th width = "15%"> Total</th>
                    <th width = "5%"> Action</th>
                </tr>
                <?php 
                // if the shopping cart has nothing  in there
                if(!empty($_SESSION['shopping_cart'])){
                    // Displays total under shopping cart table
                    $total = 0;
                    // loop through SESSIOn shopping cart array
                    foreach($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $keys => $values)
                    {
                ?>
                        <tr>
                            <!-- Product name -->
                            <td> <?php echo $values['product_name']; ?> </td>
                            <!-- Product Quantity -->
                            <td> <?php echo $values['product_quantity']; ?> </td>
                            <!-- Product Price -->
                            <td align = "right"> <?php echo $values['product_price']; ?> </td>
                            <!-- Total Price of Cars -->
                            <td align = "right"> <?php echo number_format($values['product_quantity'] * $values['product_price']); ?> </td>
                            <!-- Remove Button  -->
                            <td><button name="delete" class="delete" id="<?php echo $values['product_id']; ?>">Remove</td>
                        </tr>

                        <?php
                            // This will show total of whole shopping cart product
                            $total = $total + ($values['product_quantity'] * $values['product_price']);
                    }
                        ?>


                    <!-- // Now we want to display the total of the shopping cart -->
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan ="3" align ="right"> Total</td>
                        <!-- will show total with 2 number decimal point -->
                        <td align= "right">$ <?php echo number_format($total,2); ?></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php   
                }
                ?>
            </table>
        </div>
     </div>
 </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

`jquery`

```
<script>
// This is the code to add a product to the cart
$(document).ready(function(data){
    // When we click add to the cart button this code will execute
    $('.add_to_cart').click(function(){
        // we will use the vinNum as the id
        var product_id = $(this).attr("vinNum");
        // store the name of the car
        var product_name = $('#name' + product_id).val();
        // we get the price of the car and store it
        var product_price = $('#price' + product_id).val();
        // we fetch the quanity of cars to rent and store into the variable
        var product_quantity = $('#quantity' + product_id).val();
        // here we add the product into the cart
        var action = "Add";
        // checks if value of product quantity is greater than 0
        if(product_quantity > 0){
        /*   If the value is greater then we redirect
         to the action.php page and its a POST method
         We have the data type which is JSON and then we
         say which data we want to send
        */
            $.ajax({
                url: "action.php",
                method:"POST",
                dataType:"json",
                data:{
                    // we are sending this data to the server
                    product_id:product_id,
                    product_name:product_name,
                    product_price:product_price,
                    product_quantity:product_quantity,
                    action:action

                },
                // callback will receive data from server and store in data argument
                success:function(data){
                    // We have now received the data in JSON format
                    $('#order_table').html(data.order_table);
                    // Also display total amount in shopping cart
                    // It will show in the badge class above
                    $('.badge').text(data.cart_item);
                    alert("Product has been added to cart");
                },
                error:function(data){
            // Must enter quantity of cars to rent
            alert("Please enter number of Quantity");
                }
            });
        }
     });
});
</script>
```

`action.php`

```
<?php
    // Start the session
    // Require the database
    session_start();
    require databaseConn.php;

    // checks if prouct variable is set or not
    if(isset($_POST['product_id'])){

        $order_table = '';
        $message = '';

        // If we are trying to add cars into the cart. If we click the add button
        if($_POST['action'] == 'add'){
            // this will check if the shopping cart has something in it. If the session is set
            if(isset($_SESSION['shopping_cart'])){
                // variable for products that are already added into cart
                $is_available = 0;
                // we loop through our shopping cart and increment every time for whats in there
                foreach($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $keys => $values){
                    // this will check value of our post and check to make sure its available in our SESSION
                    if($_SESSION['shopping_cart'][$keys]['product_id'] == $_POST['product_id']){
                       // we increment and the number of products in our cart is reflected
                        $is_available++;
                        // now we put how many of that product we have for that specific car. Add product quantity to whats aleady available
                        $_SESSION['shopping_cart']['$keys']['product_quantity'] = $_SESSION['shopping_cart'][$keys]['product_quantity'] + $_POST['product_quantity'];
                    }
                }
                // if we dont have anything in the cart, then we add into the cart
                // If its already in there then we just increase anwyays 
                if($is_available < 1){
                    $item_array = array(
                        // we store the product
                        'product_id' => $_POST['product_id'],
                        'product_name' => $_POST['product_name'],
                        'product_price' => $_POST['product_price'],
                        'product_quantity' => $_POST['product_quantity']
                    );
                    // now we store our items into the session array
                    $_SESSION['shopping_cart'][] = $item_array;
                }

            }
            // If the SESSION is not set
            else{
                $item_array = array(
                    'product_id' => $_POST['product_id'],
                    'product_name' => $_POST['product_name'],
                    'product_price' => $_POST['product_price'],
                    'product_quantity' => $_POST['product_quantity']
                );
                // Now we store this array into our SESSION array
                $_SESSION['shopping_cart'][] = $item_array;
            }
            // Show the shopping car data in a table format
            $order_table .= '
               <table class="table table-bordered">
               <tr>
                <th width = "50%">Car Name</th>
                <th width = "10%">Car Name</th>
                <th width = "20%">Car Name</th>
                <th width = "15%">Car Name</th>
                <th width = "5%">Car Name</th>
               </tr>
            ';
            // checks if the session has a value or not
            if(!empty($_SESSION['shopping_cart'])){
                // this variable will to calculate toatal of shopping cart and then we display it
                $total = 0;
                // And then we loop and print the car information
                // This will all appear In our cart tab
                foreach($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $keys => $values){
                    $order_table .= '
                    <tr>

                    <td '.$values['product_name'].'</td>
                    <td '.$values['product_quantity'].' </td>
                    <td align="right">$ '.$values['product_price'].'</td>
                    <td align="right">$ '.number_format($values['product_quantity'] * $values['product_price'], 2).'</td>
                    <td><button name="delete" class="delete" id="'.$values['product_id'].'">Delete</button></td>
                   </tr>

                    ';
                    // We will get the total of the whole shopping cart and store in total
                    $total = $total + ($values['product_quantity'] * $values['product_price']);
                }
                // Now we want to show the whole total of the cart
                $order_table  .= '
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan = "3" align= "right">Total</td>
                        <td align = "right">$'.number_format($total,2).'</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>

                ';
            }
                $order_table  .= '</table>';
                $output = array(
                    'order_table' => $order_table,
                    // This will count the number of items in our shopping cart for every SESSION
                    'cart_item' => count($_SESSION['shopping_cart'])
                );
                // send data to ajax request
                // converts php array to json string and send to ajax request
                // If everything works well then we got back to our index.php and in 
                // our callback we get this as the data paramter 
                echo json_encode($output);

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Did you check the Network section of your developer tools to see if the request was fired at all?  Have you done any debugging like putting a `console.log()` statement as the first line of your click handler to see if it is triggered?

Comment: So I put `console.log("click");`  as the first line of code right after I open my `$.ajax({})` and it does not appear in my `console` I am assuming it's not being triggered? Does that make sense? @PatrickQ

Comment: Well, like I said, I'd put it as the first line of your click handler.  That will tell you whether or not you're getting into the handler at all.  Then (if you _are_ getting there) work step by step from there to see where it stops.

Comment: I am new to jQuery so it's kind of difficult to see what is exactly the problem...

Comment: I understand that.  But you don't seem to be listening to what I'm saying.  It will be easier for you to find the problem if you follow my suggestion.

Comment: okay will try to debug. Will reach out if I cant get anywhere.

Comment: I was able to fix the issue with images not showing but still cant figure out why the request is not being sent from `ajax` @PatrickQ

Comment: So what were the results of your debugging?  What is the last step where you were able to get the log to run?

Comment: I added an `alert(data)` to the end of my `ajax` and when I clicked the button `Add to Cart`,  I got an `alert(undefined)`.